# Using JS functions with Jquery in ASP Pages

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery

I'm trying to run a JS function that uses JQuery to append information to the HTML of an ASP page and I just can't get it to work. I've made some research about it but maybe it's something a lot simpler.

```
    %@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Pruebas.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        const add = (param) => {
            alert("hi");
            $("div.auto-style1").append("<p>'" + param + "'</p>");
        }

    </script>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" style="height: 26px" Text="Button" />

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <div class="container">
            some text
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

more specifically this is the function im trying to run

    <script type="text/javascript">
        const add = (param) => {
            alert("hi");
            $("div.auto-style1").append("<p>'" + param + "'</p>");
        }

    </script>
im trying to call this function from the C# code behind the page like this 

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                String p = "this is a message";
                ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "myfunction", "add('" + p + "');", true);
            
        }
```

If I try to run a JS function that produces a console log or an alert on the page it works fine. Maybe it is related to the `Postback` property in the ASP button?

If anyone can shed some light on this I will be thankful.

Comment: There isn't an element wiht the class `auto-style1` in your question. Also, make sure you're not calling `add()` before the element is rendered on the page, or wrap it in a `$(document).ready()` function

Comment: yes, i've already corrected that and tried the $(document).ready() wrap but still doesn't work,any other idea?

Comment: You could make a MRE out of this, that would help get answers

Comment: If you've already corrected it and put doc.ready, show that in your question so we can rule it out. When is the `add` function getting called? on a button click or on page load? Where is it called from?

Comment: [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

There is no any .auto-style1 class in your code. Please add a class in div to work this code.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="auto-style1">
        </div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" style="height: 26px" Text="Button" />

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>

        <div class="container">
            some text
        </div>
    </form>
```